# How do fire a query in hibernate and then access the returned records

Tags: hibernate

I have this query that I want to fire using Hibernate but I do not know the next step and I want to how to run this query and what is the result going to be in the format of and how do I access the contents.

```
String SQL_QUERY="select emp.ID, emp.password from employee where username=:username";
Query query=session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
query.setString("username", username);//How do i fire this query
```

How do I catch what has been returned and how I do I iterate through the contents that have been returned.

Comment: I assume the three lines that you have posted are not yours, anyways you can use an Iterator to browse through the contents..
Something like for(Iterator it=query.iterate();it.hasNext(););
{
your logic here. 
}

Comment: Your question shows no signs of real effort to solve the issue on your own first. Please refer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 1):

```
String SQL_QUERY="select emp.ID, emp.password from employee where username=:username";
Query query=session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
query.setString("username", username);//How do i fire this query

List list = query.list();
```

Comment: I wish I had reputation enough to upvote. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading the hibernate API to understand the different ways to retrieve and use data. I will include the link below.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html